# Matlab Shape Labelling

Tags: matlab, image-processing, shapes, area, annotate

I have a set of shapes in an image I would like to label according to their area, I have used bwboundaries to find them, and regionprops to determine their area. I would like to label them such that they are labelled different based on whether their area is above or below the threshold i have determined.

I've thought about using inserObjectAnnotation, but I'm not sure how to add on a condition based on their area into the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `TH` to be the threshold area and `BW` to be the binary image and if you are okay with labeling them as `o's` and `x's` with [**`matlab figure text`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/text.html) at their centers  (centroids to be exact), based on the thresholding, see if this satisfies your needs -

```
stats = regionprops(BW,'Area')
stats2 = regionprops(BW,'Centroid')

figure,imshow(BW)
for k = 1:numel(stats)
    xy = stats2(k).Centroid
    if (stats(k).Area>TH)
        text(xy(1),xy(2),'L') %// Large Shape
    else
        text(xy(1),xy(2),'S') %// Small Shape
    end
end
```

Sample output -

[image]

Comment: It works! But unfortunately my shapes are a little too small to include the letters clearly, is there anyway to colour them in instead of inserting text?

Comment: @KRS-fun Color the shapes you mean, i.e. fill shapes with some color?

Comment: @KRS-fun So in the output image we would have two colored shapes only, one color for smaller than threshold area shapes and rest of the shapes would be filled with the second color?

Comment: I've already ticked your answer as you've answered my original question

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CC = bwconncomp(BW,conn)`.

To get the number of pixels of every connected compontent you can use:

```
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
```

In `CC.PixelIdxList` you have a list of all found objects and the indices of the pixels belonging to the components. I guess to label your areas you could do something like:

```
for ind = 1:size(CC.PixelIdxList,2)
   Image(CC.PixelIdxList{ind}) = ind;
end
```

Comment: By labeling, OP probably means annotating, that's why the mention of `insertobjectannotation`

Comment: Ok, sounds correct. I understood something else with labeling because i didn't know `insertobjectannotation` (which i don't have in Matlab 2012a).

Comment: yeah I understood the samething you did, until I saw that longish term. In fact you can look into its online documentation - http://www.mathworks.in/help/vision/ref/insertobjectannotation.html